# Show $f(x,y,z) = \frac{\log(y/x)}{\log(z/x)}$ is quasi concave for $x \ge y > 0$, $x \ge z > 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I'd like to show that
$$
\frac{\log\frac{y_1+y_2}{x_1+x_2}}{\log\frac{z_1+z_2}{x_1+x_2}}
\ge
\min\left\{
\frac{\log(y_1/x_1)}{\log(z_1/x_1)},
\frac{\log(y_2/x_2)}{\log(z_2/x_2)}
\right\}.
$$
This would follow if $f(x,y,z) = 
\frac{\log(y/x)}{\log(z/x)}$ was quasi concave.

One way to show this is if $f(x,y,z)\ge\alpha$ defines a convex set for all $\alpha\ge 0$.
Plotting for various values of $\alpha$, this is clearly the case.

From the first order condition, it suffices if
$f(\vec y) \le f(\vec x) \implies \nabla f(\vec x)^T(\vec y-\vec x) \ge 0.$
Let $x'\ge y',z'$ be such that $f(x',y',z')\le f(x,y,z)$ then we must show

$$z \log \left(\frac{x}{z}\right) (y x'-x y')
\ge y \log \left(\frac{x}{y}\right) (z x'-x z'),$$
which unfortunately doesn't seem any easier.

Alternatively, since $\log x$ is quasi-linear, perhaps it suffices to show that $(x-y)/(x-z)$ is quasi-concave? I don't know a theorem to this effect, however.

Do you see a nice argument I might use to simplify this problem? Perhaps just tackling the original inequality directly?

Comment: Could you clearly define the domain? Can $x/y/z$ all be negative?

Comment: @LinAlg Right! They are all positive. They are also at most 1, though that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Ok, just to make sure, $\log(z/x)$ can be both negative and positive, right? Or did you mean $x \geq y > 0$ and $x > z > 0$?

Comment: @LinAlg I didn't even think of that obvious ambiguity! It is always negative, or if we write it as $\log(x/y)/\log(x/z)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give you a possible method. Consider the superlevel set $\{(x,y,z) : \log(y/x) / \log(z/x) \geq \alpha, x \geq y > 0, x > z > 0 \}$. Since $\log(z/x)$ is negative, the sublevel set is equivalent to the set:
$$\{(x,y,z) : \log(y/x) \leq \alpha \log(z/x), x \geq y > 0, x > z > 0 \}$$
$$=\{(x,y,z) : y \leq x^{1-\alpha}z^{\alpha}, x \geq y > 0, x > z > 0 \}.$$
Consider the Hessian of $f(x,z) = x^{1-\alpha}z^{\alpha}$. If it is negative semidefinite, the set is convex and you are done. Otherwise, try the same but with $x$ or $z$ on one side.

Comment: The eigenvalues of the Hessian are $0$ and $-(1-\alpha) a x^{-\alpha-1} z^{\alpha-2} \left(x^2+z^2\right)$, so I guess it is negative semidefinite for all $\alpha\le1$. That suffices for my purposes! Is $\{(x,y,z) : y \le f(x,y)\}$ always convex when $f$ is concave?

Comment: @ThomasAhle the answer to your last question is yes; the equivalent set in convex optimization is $\{x : f(x) \leq 0\}$ where $f$ is convex.